# Handbrake Engaged for 9-10 km Driving Roughly 80 km/h

Tags: automatic-transmission, mitsubishi, handbrake

- Make: Mitsubishi
- Model: Pajero Intercooler 2800
- Handling: Automatic
- Year: 1992

I forgot to release the handbrake on my car this morning. I didn't realize I forgot to release it until I had driven it approximately 10 km.  I reached a top speed of 100 km/h.

I did smell rubber burning somewhere while I was on the road, but could not tell if that was coming from my car.  Please help.

Comment: I suggested an edit to your question. If it gets accepted, I removed the part about RPM, as that should really be a separate question since it's not really about the handbrake.

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking, keeping the parking brake engaged while driving the vehicle will heat your brake pads and potentially wear them down rapidly. If you're not hearing any grinding or squeaking on your brake pads it is PROBABLY not a problem.  However, for peace of mind I'd suggest having someone inspect the brake pads for deformity or cracking, just if you want to play it safe.

Answer (score 0):

If the parking was engaged for 10 km at 100 km/h. The burning rubber smell is from your rear tires losing about 20000km of tread all in one spot.

Comment: That's unlikely. The only time I've been able to lock the wheels using the handbrake was on ice. Plus the Pajero of that age has an old-school 4WD system with permanent drive to the rear wheels, and manual hubs for engaging the front wheels. Pull the handbrake sufficiently to lock the rear wheels on that setup, and you're not going to move at all.